# how to prevent fs.writeFile from overwriting existing files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am creating test files from swagger API definition file. I use `fs.writeFile` for  creating test files (which are mostly stubs, so I need to add details to these files manually). Now the problem is that whenever I generate the test files again, it overwrites all the existing files as well.

So, my question is, is there some option for `fs.writeFile` that we can set to specify that if a file is already existing, do not overwrite it?

Most obvious way seems to be to first check if a file exists and only generate it if it doesn't exist already. But, if there is some option in `fs.writeFile` itself, that would be more convenient and compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fs.writeFile** don't have any options as such to check if file already existing.

I would recommend to use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). Below is one of the solution.

```
async function writeFile(f) {
    try {
        if ((await fs.pathExists(f)) === false) {
            await fs.outputFile(f, 'hello!');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

writeFile('/tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/file.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I was looking for some option for this but as you mentioned I think there's no such option available. So, that answers my question. Thanks again :)